# Adding cost to edges of an adjacency matrix in C++

Tags: c++, graph

I have to implement a matrix in c++ and preform Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm on it. I have made a graph using an adjacency matrix by adding in the vertices and the edges of the graph but I have no idea how to add a cost to the edges.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
graph::graph(int vertexCount){ 

    this->vertexCount = vertexCount;
    adjacencyMatrix = new bool*[vertexCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < vertexCount; i++) {
        adjacencyMatrix[i] = new bool[vertexCount];
        for (int j = 0; j < vertexCount; j++)
            adjacencyMatrix[i][j] = false;
    }
}

void graph::addEdge(int i, int j) {

    if (i >= 0 && i < vertexCount && j > 0 && j < vertexCount) {
        adjacencyMatrix[i][j] = true;
        adjacencyMatrix[j][i] = true;
    }
}
```

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction on what to add to this to add the cost to my edges?

Comment: Why not, instead of having a `bool` matrix, have a `float` or `int` matrix!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can change adjacencyMatrix type to type other than bool (uint for example), and then add there a value.
Like in example on wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix